# How do you use quotes to remove multiple sets of quotes from columns in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to clean some data in R, but I am having trouble working through the regex. I tried using the noquote function in R. But, it didn't seem to help

```r
data %>% head()
     X..Latitude..  X..Longitude..
1 ""52","3726380"" ""4","8941060""
2 ""52","4103320"" ""4","7490690""
3 ""52","3828340"" ""4","9204560""
4 ""52","4362550"" ""4","8167080""
5 ""52","3615820"" ""4","8854790""
6 ""52","3702150"" ""4","8951670""
```

```r
data %>% noquote()
1 ""52","3726380"" ""4","8941060""
2 ""52","4103320"" ""4","7490690""
3 ""52","3828340"" ""4","9204560""
4 ""52","4362550"" ""4","8167080""
5 ""52","3615820"" ""4","8854790""
6 ""52","3702150"" ""4","8951670""
```

**Reproducible data**

```r
structure(list(X..Latitude.. = c("\"\"52\",\"3726380\"\"", "\"\"52\",\"4103320\"\"", "\"\"52\",\"3828340\"\"", "\"\"52\",\"4362550\"\"", "\"\"52\",\"3615820\"\"", "\"\"52\",\"3702150\"\""), X..Longitude.. = c("\"\"4\",\"8941060\"\"", "\"\"4\",\"7490690\"\"", "\"\"4\",\"9204560\"\"", "\"\"4\",\"8167080\"\"", "\"\"4\",\"8854790\"\"", "\"\"4\",\"8951670\"\"")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: structure(list(X..Latitude.. = c("\"\"52\",\"3726380\"\"", "\"\"52\",\"4103320\"\"", 
"\"\"52\",\"3828340\"\"", "\"\"52\",\"4362550\"\"", "\"\"52\",\"3615820\"\"", 
"\"\"52\",\"3702150\"\""), X..Longitude.. = c("\"\"4\",\"8941060\"\"", 
"\"\"4\",\"7490690\"\"", "\"\"4\",\"9204560\"\"", "\"\"4\",\"8167080\"\"", 
"\"\"4\",\"8854790\"\"", "\"\"4\",\"8951670\"\"")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the data was read incorrectly.

A way to correct this after reading the data is to remove all the quotes and replace `","` with `"."` to specify decimal numbers. We can also clean up the name of the columns.

```
data[] <- lapply(data, function(x) gsub('"', '', sub(',', '.', x)))
names(data) <- gsub('[X.]', '', names(data))
data

#    Latitude Longitude
#1 52.3726380 4.8941060
#2 52.4103320 4.7490690
#3 52.3828340 4.9204560
#4 52.4362550 4.8167080
#5 52.3615820 4.8854790
#6 52.3702150 4.8951670
```

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to work. Is there a way to do this when reading the file-in through readr?

Comment: There should be but I don't have the file which you are using so I am not really sure how to do it.

Comment: `gsub` and `sub` are vectorized. No need of `lapply` hence `gsub('"', '', sub(',', '.', as.matrix(dt)))`

Answer (score 1):

in base R you could just re-read your data:

```
read.table(text=do.call(paste, data), sep=" ", dec=",",col.=c("Latitude","Longitude"))

  Latitude Longitude
1 52.37264  4.894106
2 52.41033  4.749069
3 52.38283  4.920456
4 52.43626  4.816708
5 52.36158  4.885479
6 52.37022  4.895167
```